# index match value error

Tags: excel, indexing, match

When I try to do an index-match lookup with 2 conditions, I always get a #Value! error even though I seem to be doing everything about in the exact same way as every excel tutorial out there.

Need it for a file with over 400'000 rows, so anything manual isn't really an option. Any advice? Thanks a million in advance!

*Table 1*
**X1        X2          Y**
Apple   01.05.2010  CHF 10
Apple   30.02.2010  CHF 15
Mango   20.01.2008  CHF 5
Mango   10.12.2011  CHF 4
…   …   …

*Table 2*
**X1        X2          Y**

Apple   01.05.2010  #VALUE!

Formula in field Y of Table 2:

```
=INDEX(D4:D7;MATCH(H4&I4;B4:B7&C4:C7;0))
```

[image: See picture example here]

Comment: Have you entered it as an array formula (ctrl+shift+enter)?

Comment: Which Swiss canton will have a calendar which has 30 days in february?

Comment: @Jonathan: that did the trick. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Axel Richter: Just tipped in some random numbers to make a simplified version of the actual calculations.

Comment: Glad I could help, I've posted as an answer so it's easier to see.

Answer (score 1):

When you enter more than one range into a MATCH, you need to enter as an array formula i.e. type the formula and press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER.

You will know if this has worked because Excel will surround the formula with curly brackets `{}`.

Answer (score 0):

Max nothing is wrong with your Formula, you simply press F2,, and press Ctrl +Shift +DEL since it's an Array formula.